# Using mysql query and result in php?

Tags: php, mysql, environment

I've had some help from bluefleet (BF) with a mysql query, i now need to use that query in a php environment, this is what i've come up with, firstly can you tell me if it's correct and secondly do i need to release the query after i've done something with the result?

Here's the query

```
    $myquery= "select sum(total)
from
(
    SELECT count(*) as total
    FROM " .TABLE_PREFIX."tview v
    where v.ipaddress = $ips
    union all
    SELECT count(*) as total
    FROM " .TABLE_PREFIX."tview1 v1
    where v1.ipaddress = $ips
    union all
    SELECT count(*) as total
    FROM " .TABLE_PREFIX."tview3` v3
    where v3.ipaddress = $ips
) src";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($myquery)) {

If($row !=0){
echo "NOT EMPTY";
}else{
echo "EMPTY";
}
}
```

Comment: Quick question: Why do you use the `mysql_*` functions? We are currently doing a survey, just speak openly about your motivation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine. Use these statements to execute the query and get the count:

```
    $result = mysql_query($myquery);

    $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

    If($rowCount !=0){
       echo "NOT EMPTY";
    }else{
      echo "EMPTY";
    }
```

To FREE up the result:

```
   mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: so i have the " .TABLE_PREFIX." statements and " correct? or should i change all the inside quotes to single quotes just leaving the start and end quotes as doubles? thanks for rest, do i have to release the result like $result FREE?

Comment: @Silo: Sorry I missed to look at the quotes. Please replace all double quotes with single quotes. Also wrap `.TABLE_PREFIX.` in the single quotes. I updated the answer with $result free statement but don't think that is really required.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a lot going on here but keep in mind that php going into sql looks like this:

```
                    UPDATE USER SET MONEY = '$money2'
                    WHERE ID = '$uID'"
```

Notice the single ' ' around the variable and then $ to indicate the php variable you want to set

Comment: Ah!, thanks you've pretty much answered half my comment to Yogendra above, single quotes all the way through (and around the variables as they're strings:)) and double quotes start and end, thanks you :)